# Best way to have a single Entity using Magicalrecord

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm looking for the best solution to implement this behavior:

I have an Entity called Customer and this will have only a single entry on Core Data, because the Customer will be only ONE.

What's the best solution to implement this? Is everytime check if the Entity exists before creating?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use for single object [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults].

But if you prefer use CoreData, write this:

```
Customer* customer = [Customer MR_findFirst];
if (customer != nil)
{
    //do something with it
} else
{
    [Customer MR_importFromObject:JSONToImport];        
}
```

BDW:

**MR_importFromObject** method automatically check if exists entity with specific id (for id key it use  attribute of your entity name plus "ID". (in your case ***"customerID"***) or key that named "mappedKeyName".

And if entity with this key already exist - Magical Record just update this entity.

So, if you specify this value it in your entity, just write:

```
[Customer MR_importFromObject:JSONToImport];
```

Comment: This is the exactly approach I'm doing! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If there's only a single instance, the best solution is usually to not put it in Core Data. It gives you very little, and adds complexities like the one you're seeing. Save the necessary information in a property list, or even in user defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the entity exists before creating a new one is a good idea.

You can fetch all entities of your customer entity type and delete them all before adding a new one is another method.

You could also have a simple method that gets the current customer or creates one and then update all it's properties.

It sort of depends on how you get the data and what you want to happen with the related objects.

Comment: Counting the number of instances of the entity could also be a check mechanism.